# Microsoft Word changing document view on scroll

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, scrolling

I have a friend who is trying to view a Word document, consisting of a large table (nothing to do with me), that was fine until today. Whenever they scroll down past a certain limit, the content on the page is replicated once and after that the table cells are blank. The view also switches to Normal·

They think that the document was last opened in OpenOffice (version 3.3.0, which opens the document fine now), could this cause it? Its Word 2000. What can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the OpenOffice Word format is too advanced for Word 2000. The generated format is probably compatible with newer versions of Word, because Word 2000 is not any longer exactly a supported product.

Try to save in some other format which is acceptable for Word 2000 (you can see the list by doing in Word 2000 File / Open and regarding the drop-box). For example, maybe the even older RTF format may work.

Comment: +1 for RTF. I'm surprised the 97-2003 format is causing issues. It's pretty consistent between 2000, XP and 2003. Interesting ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll let you know whether it works tomorrow (UTC), when I next see the person who had the problem.